# weird numbering in master document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

I have a master document and several sub documents. Master document has very strange looking numbering:

[image]

On the left side number how it looks when I open master document. On the right side how it looks when I open sub document and save it (just save, without performing any actual modification). Numbering looks good until I reopen master document. If I reopen I need to save sub document again to get it right.

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hope and pray by the sounds of it :) Try some of the tips on http://word.mvps.org/faqs/general/RecoverMasterDocs.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a blank document and setting  everything back to the default settings, then saving that blank document over your existing `Normal.doc`/`Normal.docx` template; it sounds as if this is the default behaviour that your document inherts whenever it is opened as it would presumably be based on the `Normal.doc`/`Normal.docx` template.